# why does my button look different on on phone and pc

Tags: html

i have the following button on my page:

```
<button style="margin-left:20px; width:40px; height:40px; font-size:30px;" onclick="reload(0)">⟲</button>
```

on my computer it looks fine(the symbol almost fills the button) but on my phone the Symbol is much smaller(compared to the button). Why is that and how do i fix it?

Comment: You didn't provide any screenshots, but it may be due to differences in how the ⟲ character is rendered on your computer versus smartphone.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Are you sure to have inserted the right responsive-friendly metatags?

Comment: However is really not recommended to use fonts to do icons, you should really consider using a .png or a .svg instead

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend  
 instead of using text just add this code and it will give you a very nice icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and it will will be like that:
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/refresh 
add to your button and it will work 
otherwise use svg or png format instead of text 
no one use text for button icon.